# Is it possible to pass a function pointer as a block argument directly?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Say I have a function that expects a block:

```
void foo(Foo (^block)(Bar));
```

And say I have a function with the same signature, except not a block:

```
Foo myFunction(Bar);
```

I can do this:

```
foo(^(Bar bar) { return myFunction(bar); });
```

But I would rather do this, which would be equivalent if it worked:

```
foo(&myFunction);
```

If I try to, XCode says:

```
No matching function for call to 'foo'
```

A block is a function pointer together with some context, so on that level it seems reasonable to want to use a plain function pointer as a block with an empty context. Is it possible?

Comment: A block is not a function pointer with context. It is a pointer to the context, which happens to contain a function pointer.

Comment: Even so, it seems trivial for the language to make a context with the given function pointer in it and nothing else. But I guess it's not implemented. (Maybe it would require C++-style overloading to be reasonable). Not a huge deal.

Comment: It isn't trivial;  you have to be able to pass a reference to the context into the function for the function's body to be able to retrieve said context -- to retrieve the captured variables.  Overloading isn't going to help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> A block is a function pointer together with some context, so on that
>   level it seems reasonable to want to use a plain function pointer as a
>   block with an empty context. Is it possible?

The problem, though, is that a block is not *a function pointer together with some context*.

A block captures executable code during compilation and state during execution.   The executable code follows the C ABI in terms of passing arguments *but*, like method calls, it has some very specific requirements.   Translating it to a C function declaration, a block that returns a `BOOL` and takes a single `int` argument would look like this:

```
BOOL blockLikeFunc(void *block, int arg) { ... }
```

That is, the first argument to the block's "function" must be a pointer to the block itself.

Thus, no, you can't just rip out the block's "function" pointer and cast it to/from a C function.

Answer (score 0):

> but a block is a function pointer

Except that it isn't. If you want to pass a function pointer as an argument, try this:

```
int FooDouble(int x)
{
    return x * 2;
}

- (int)callFunction:(int (*)(int))function withArgument:(int)arg
{
    return function(arg);
}

NSLog(@"%d", [self callFunction:FooDouble withArgument:21]);
```

This outputs `42`.

Comment: "a block is a function pointer" and "a block is a function pointer *together with some context*" do not mean the same thing. I said the latter. And I do know how to use function pointers. Thanks.

Comment: @illissius In this case, what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
@import Foundation;

@implementation NSObject(extra)
+ (int)callFunction:(int (^)(int))function withArgument:(int)arg
{
    return function(arg);
}
@end;

int main() {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"doubleIt(3) returns %d", [NSObject callFunction:^(int param) { return param * param; } withArgument:3]);
    } return 0;
}
```